# Force Spring to always report exceptions as JSON

Tags: spring, web-services, rest

How do I force Spring to always convert uncaught exception to JSON instead of HTML page?

This is what I get when request is made from Chrome's REST client plugin:

```
{
timestamp: 1425041457798
status: 404
error: "Not Found"
exception: "com.some.my.Exception"
message: "/rrr does not exist"
path: "/test/rrr"
}
```

But this is what I get when I access it from browser or from `Jersey API` (you see parsed HTML):

## Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Feb 27 13:37:27 CET 2015There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).No message available

I know this can be done somehow by setting the request headers but I want JSON response to be the only variant.

Answer (score 0):

First we need add some exception resolver for exception that trows inside controllers. I prefer extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and add own method, but there is a great article on spring.io: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

After that if you still get following page you can override `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController`. There are an example: `BasicErrorController`. But this works only if you use spring boot application with embedded container. For example, if you will create war file form spring boot project and will deploy under tomcat, you will get standard tomcat error page.

So this mean that `ErrorController` is not common solution.

In my case i throws exceptions inside filters, that why `/error` page shown. So solution will be write own filter that converts exceptions to JSON representation. This solution should work for every container/server, and you can get more information about exception.